# Download file from PostgreSQL bytea escape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, encoding

I have some issue to allow users download file, which stored in PostgreSQL bytea escaped field (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html).

```
1.9.3p385 :023 > data = PG::Connection.unescape_bytea(m[:data])
 => "JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAg\r\nUiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSA+Pgpzd..."
1.9.3p385 :023 > data.encoding.name
 => "ASCII-8BIT" 
1.9.3p385 :023 > data.bytesize
 => 3878164
```

But when I used "send_data" or "send_file" with tempfile, I getting file in invalid format (this is pdf file). It much bigger, than original and not opening by pdf readers.

This data in field is mime part of email. If I build raw email from all this parts (using boundary as separator), this email will contain valid pdf attachment.

How should I convert this data to bytes to allow user download this file separately?

Answer (score 0):

See the following: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27845&group_id=234&atid=967

The syntax is something like PGConn.unescape_bytea($field);

Depending on your version of pg, you may need to upgrade that gem